# PyCharm: formatting dataframes in SciView: what are the options? Can I separate the thousands with a comma?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

The Scientific View mode of PyCharm displays pandas dataframes and numpy arrays.

At the bottom right there is an option to change the format (see screenshot below). E.g.

`%.2f` = 2 decimal digits

`%.3e` = scientific notation with 3 decimal digits. e.g. 3.456e-2 for 3.456%

I have 3 questions:

1. What are all the options, are they documented anywhere? I couldn't find anything on the PyCharm website nor online.
2. Is there an option to separate the thousands with a comma? In Python I'd use `{0:,.2f}` to separate the thousands with a comma and show 2 decimal digits. I have tried many variants of this, none seems to work
3. Is there an option for percentages? `%.2%` does not work
4. Is it possible to format different columns of a dataframe differently?

To be clear, I am talking about formatting the display in PyCharm only. I am not talking about how to modify the dataframe so that the number 1000.152 becomes the string "1,000.15"

[image: Data view screenshot]